# Select not showing text vue 3

Tags: vue.js

i copy example from https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/ , but it dosnt work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRbVk.png)

```
   <v-select
                                    v-model="select"
                                    :items="items"
                                    item-text="state"
                                    item-value="abbr"

                                    return-object
                                    single-line
                            ></v-select>  


 data() {
            return {
                select: {state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL'},
                items: [
                    {state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL'},
                    {state: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA'},
                    {state: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE'},
                    {state: 'California', abbr: 'CA'},
                    {state: 'New York', abbr: 'NY'},
                ],
 }
}
```

package json:

> "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.3",

if i click on dropdown element i get error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading '__asyncLoader')
> at isAsyncWrapper (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2246:1)
> at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6034:1)
> at unmountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6185:1)
> at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6065:1)
> at unmountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6156:1)
> at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6041:1)
> at unmountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6185:1)
> at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6065:1)
> at unmountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6156:1)
> at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd

:6041:1)

Comment: You should initialize the `select` variable either as NULL or as a reference to one of the array items from `items` - otherwise the 2 Object instances won't match.

Comment: @IVOGELOV i remove v-model="select" The error is still there

Comment: What is the text of the error?

Comment: @IVOGELOV i mean text not showing

Comment: Try `select: null,` instead of `select: {state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL'}`

Comment: @IVOGELOV it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have a CodePen or CodeSandbox to demonstrate how it does not work?